# Why do we need ViewChild() when we can communicate with Child Controller using @Output decorator

Tags: angular

Please help me. I am new to Angular. Just started learning Angular. I want to know when we have `@Output` decorator for communication between child and Parent Component, then what is the need of `ViewChild()`. Using `ViewChild()` also we are accessing child.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In brief

1. You use `@Output` to create a "event" so you "binding" that the
   parent can listen. So the parent becomes like

   ```
       <app-child (output)="myFunction($event)"></app-child>
   ```

   See that you only perfom an action when "something" happens in child
   component (that it's when you use `this.output.emit(new-value)`
2. You use ViewChild from parent to "reach" the children and to have
   access to all the variables and method of the Child

   ```
   {{child.variable}}
   <app-child></app-child>

   @ViewChild(ChildComponent) child:ChildComponent
   ```
3. You use ViewChildren when you want to mannage a list of Children

   ```
   <ng-container *ngFor="let i of [0,1,2]">
   <app-child #child
      [class.selected]="i==indexSelected"></app-child> </ng-container>

   @ViewChildren('child') children:QueryList<ChildComponent>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

`ViewChild` has a different use than `Output`, is used to get a reference of the component we use in the template, for example if your template looks something like that:

```
<div>
    <color-sample [color]="primary" #primaryColorSample>
    </color-sample>
</div>
```

you have this custom `color-sample` component, and you want to get a reference to this component in order to (for example) set the component colors configuration or to get the current color value - you can get access to this component in the `.ts` file, like that:

```
export class AppComponent implements  AfterViewInit {
  .....
    
  @ViewChild(ColorSampleComponent) primarySampleComponent: ColorSampleComponent;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // this where you can access the viewChild and work with it
  }  

  .....
}
```

as you can see in the example `Viewchild` is not accessible before `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle method and we won't try to access it from `ngOnInit`

this is one common use of `ViewChild` - hope it helps :)